# Cannot Upgrade from python 3.5.2 to 3.6

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 18.1

The distro has pre-installed python 2.7 and python 3.5.2 .

what i would like to do is to upgrade python 3.5.2 to 3.6 or 3.6.1

i have tried this on the command line:
`sudo apt-get upgrade python3`

and i get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

what should i do to upgrade python to 3.6 or 3.6.1 ?

Comment: Should apply to mint as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Comment: Python 3.6 is not part of Mint's software repos yet. You can either install from [source](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-linuxmint/) or use a [third party PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)

Comment: @KlausD. thank you this did work..it did not upgrade the previously installed version but at least it did install 3.6.1

Answer (score 5):

Just point the ppa, update and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: This command does not update, instead install a separate setup for python3.6 .

Comment: `ERROR: '~deadsnakes user or team does not exist`